# How to implement this sort of layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the image i want to implement in android.

Please help me how to design xml layout and what should be in

[image]

Comment: Use circle image view and `Linear Layout` horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .xml page use this code :

```
<com.xxx.xxx.xxx.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_round"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/doctor" />
```

For `RoundedImageView` you have to copy paste this:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

        Bitmap bmm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), true);

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
        else
            sbmp = bmp;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

        paint.setAnti`enter code here`Alias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented with Recycler view if you want to scroll the images as well, to Scroll the Recycler view Horizontally you can use below code.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView_Activity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

You can add **Recycler view(With images)** and **TextView(Having value +194 shared)** in a horizontal layout and once we scroll on the list you can set the pending element count in the textview.

If your requirement is not to scroll the images then you can simply add the images in the linear layout and add a text view to show the count.